# Is there a CSS rule that causes clicked links change properties on destination site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Beginner question. Lets say I have 4 different links pointing to the same webpage, is it possible to change the destination page's properties based on which link got me there? Example: I click link1 and the background on the destination is yellow. link2 causes it to be black.

So my question would be do I need to create 4 different copies of the website for the 4 different links? Or is there a CSS rule or something else that would achieve the same thing, without creating 4 copies?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You would need to check the referrer using a method from whichever framework you built the website in, then you could apply a particular css class conditionally.

Comment: e.g. Javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use the **:target** pseudo selector in css to change styles based on the **#anchor** of the URL. For example below, `www.mysite.com/test.html#black`

```css
div#black:target {
 background-color: black;
}

div#yellow:target {
 background-color: yellow;
}

div.page {
 min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="black">
      <div id="yellow">
        <div class="page">
          <h1>Content</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```